# How to solve this inequality where two zeroes of different factors of the numerator are the same? How do we solve this using sign-scheme method?

Tags: inequality

$\dfrac{(e^x-1)x^{49}(1-x)(x-3)^{50}}{(x-2)(x-4)}\geqslant0$

Here, when I find zeroes of $(e^x-1)$ and $x^{49}$, both of them are zero. The solution set for this inequality in my book is given as $x\in(-\infty, 1] ∪ (2,3]$ but I can't figure out if I'm making some error or the book has a misprint. Please help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually the solution given by your book is wrong, in fact the correct solution set is $\;(-\infty,1]\cup(2,4)\;.$ See my answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

I naïvely thought the book was correct and didn’t bother to scrutinise it - why do we get so many questions with mistaken books? Anyway, as Antonio says, the book erred and the second interval should be $(2,4)$.

OP:

There are just other zeros of the function. The zero of $x=0$ is contained in that interval given in your textbook, as are the zeroes of $x=1$ and $x=3$. The second interval is open at $2$ since $x=2$ is a pole of the inequality (division by zero) but all points just above it give positive values.

Moreover, when $x$ is negative, we have $e^x\lt1$, so the first bracket $(e^x-1)$ is negative, but then it is multiplied by $x^{49}$, an odd power, so the two negatives cancel to a positive. If you step through the remaining terms you find the whole inequality is positive for negative $x$: $(1-x)$ is positive, $(x-3)^{50}$, an even power, is still positive, the denominators $(x-2)$ and $(x-4)$ are both negative, multiplying to make a positive.

EDIT:

The graph of $e^x$ looks like this:

[image]

Notice how for all real $x$, it is greater than $0$, and also notice how it is always greater than $1$ when $x\gt0$. It grows very quickly - *exponentially*!

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer!

Comment: You're welcome @DivyanshAdwani. Note that my answer wasn't complete; I left the proof that $x\in(1,2)$ and $x\in(3,\infty)$ don't satisfy the inequality up to you. Try it as an exercise

Comment: hey, I tried but I can't figure out how to determine the sign of $(e^x-1)$ when I assume the value of $x$ to be 5. I feel like I'd have to know the value of $e$ first.

Comment: @DivyanshAdwani The value of $e$ is a constant: $2.718128...$, from memory. It is a very famous and important constant/function/idea/.... anyway, its precise value doesn't matter too much here. The point is, any strictly positive base $a$, to the power of a strictly positive power $b$, $a^b\gt1$. "Strictly" means greater than $0$. The number $e$ is [well worth researching](https://www.google.com/search?q=intuitive+explanation+of+e&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB943GB943&oq=intuitive+explanation+of+e&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i22i30l3.4682j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @DivyanshAdwani I edited a picture into my answer

Comment: Gotcha! Appreciate you!

Comment: Actually the solution given in OP’s book is wrong, in fact the correct solution set is $\;(-\infty,1]\cup(2,4)\;.$

Comment: @DivyanshAdwani Yes - I didn’t bother to scrutinise the book - the book is wrong, it should be up to $4$ as Antonio says

Answer (score 2):

Since $\;x(e^x-1)>0\;,\;x^{48}>0\;$ for any $\;x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\;$ and $\;(x-3)^{50}>0\;$ for any $\;x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{3\}\;,\;$ your inequality is equivalent to

$\dfrac{1-x}{(x-2)(x-4)}\geqslant0\quad\lor\quad x=0\quad\lor\quad x=3\;.$

Moreover ,

$1-x\geqslant0\iff x\leqslant1\;,$

$(x-2)(x-4)>0\iff x<2\;\lor\;x>4\;.$

Consequently ,

$\dfrac{1-x}{(x-2)(x-4)}\geqslant0\iff x\leqslant1\;\lor\;2<x<4\;.$

Hence the solution set for your inequality is :

$(-\infty,1]\cup(2,4)\;.$